# SQL Server 2014 - Full text index never stops populating

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, full-text-search

I have a server that is running SQL Server 2014. I have full text indexes on some of my tables in my databases. The problem is that it's always saying populating and it never finishes. So my queries with contains in them never return anything.

I've compared this server to another server of mine that is working. The Full text feature is installed the service is running. They both are logging in as the same user.

The SQLFT logs have nothing in them. The event viewer is showing no errors.

Running a [status query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727911/how-can-i-know-when-sql-full-text-index-population-is-finished) on the full text catalog returns.

> LastPopulated                       PopulateStatus
>   1990-01-01 00:00:00.000     Full Population In Progress

running

```
EXEC sp_fulltext_table 'fullTextIndex', 'start_full'
```

or

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Table
START FULL POPULATION;
```

returns

> Warning: Request to start a full-text index population on table or
>   indexed view 'fullTextIndex' is ignored because a population is
>   currently active for this table or indexed view.

The CPU is low and there is about 3 gigs of memory available.

Looking at performance monitor for SQL Full-text filter Daemon it shows its not doing anything. Also stopping the population and restarting doesn't help nor does restarting the service.

Any Ideas on the issue or what to look at next?

**UPDATE:** I've still never be able to find the cause of this issue. The solution for now will be to migrate the databases off the machine that has the never ending full text index population.

**UPDATE 2:** While clearly not the same issue has I originally had, this did come up again for me and restarting the SQL server and machine fixed it. In my original issue this didn't work and we just moved our databases off that server.

Comment: which change tracking is set: SET CHANGE_TRACKING {MANUAL | AUTO | OFF} ?

Comment: @JulienVavasseur Change tracking is set to Off, but that shouldn't matter as I was manually building the full text index with start full population Correct?

Comment: I thought it was on auto and running or doing sth. I think I would set it to manual, then run stop population and then try a start full again.

Comment: Changed tracking to manual, and then tried to stop population through msSqlMS and population wouldn't stop. Change tracking back to off and I could stop population and start again. No changes, the issue is persisting. At this point I'm convinced something is wrong with the sql server or the machine. But what a strange issue.

Comment: does ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Table
STOP POPULATION work ? and what is the error?

Comment: With change tracking set to manual:

Warning: The ongoing population is necessary to ensure an up-to-date index. If needed, stop change tracking first, and then deactivate the full-text index population.